# C# hide ctrl key in mouse_event

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent

I have a situation where I'm trying to send a `mouse-click` when the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key is pressed.

What I'm finding is that the application that receives the mouse click event is interpreting the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key as down.

What can I do to `release` the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key in my code before sending my mouse event?

I'm using `mouse_event` to send the `LeftDown` message, if that's a useful clue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Return true from this overridden method in your control if you want to prevent the default behaviour:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Ctrl)
    {
        //send mouse event
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using keybd_event() before using mouse_event:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int extraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern short MapVirtualKey(int wCode, int wMapType);

    // ...
        keybd_event((int)Keys.ControlKey, (byte)MapVirtualKey((int)Keys.ControlKey, 0), 2, 0); // Control Up                
        // ... call mouse_event() ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.  I was afraid that someone would assume I was working with a WinForms control :)

I found the Windows Input Simulator library (http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) was able to get me what I needed.  I use that to send the "key up" message before I do the "mouse down" message, and everything works great.

Thanks again for the answers!